# How to disable filtering on canvas with webgpu context

Tags: css, html5-canvas, webgpu

I use webgpu to render to canvas. I need pixelated result but got blurred.
I tried to disable it with css

```
  .canvas {
    image-rendering: pixelated;
    transform: scale(32);
    transform-origin: top left;
  }
```

What I got: [blurred image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbRoY.png)
What I need: [pixelated image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMEHa.png)
[full sources](https://github.com/Defernus/cells/blob/question1/cells-web/src/components/Grid.svelte)

Comment: Please include the most relevant parts of your code in the question itself. When you will solve your issue, you will certainly apply the fix on your repo, and the question would be moot, and unable to really help future readers.

Comment: And to your issue, this is a Chrome bug, please report it at https://crbug.com You can workaround that by forcing a repaint of your canvas though CSS:  `.grid {
  image-rendering: pixelated;
  transform: scale(32);
  transform-origin: top left;
  animation: fix-image-rendering-bug .0001s;
} 
@keyframes fix-image-rendering-bug {
  from { opacity: 0.9999; }
  to { opacity: 1; }
}`

Comment: Note that this is very probably related to https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=993762, where I did mention this question (which only raise the need for an [MCVE] in the question itself), but I believe opening its own issue for WebGPU is fine.